# Unable to determine Android SDK

Tags: android-studio, cordova, build.gradle

Cordova creates a package and imports it to android studio

Following Error:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Users/admin/Projects/android_App/Android_1/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 112

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ': app'.
> Unable to determine Android SDK directory.

* Try:
Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ': app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle`
```

There is no plugin.
I have updated all Cordova, npm, android studio with the latest one. But still not able to solve this issue.

SDK tools uninstall and install again.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.
Its a Corova package issue. By default under android local.properties file will be creating while adding cordova platform android. Now that file is not adding.

Create new file --> Project--> Platform --> android-->  local.properties

and keep this --> sdk.dir=/path/sdk example [**sdk.dir=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk**]

then it starts working.

Thanks.

Comment: what was the issue? it means still, you cant solve it?

Comment: I was preparing android project from ionic and got above issue.
I solve it by adding `local.properties` in Android level.

Comment: Using Ionic3 on Windows - in my case it wanted with double slashes in the local.properties: `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`
I saved the local.properties in my project and copied it in the `after_platform_add` hook

Answer (score 6):

## gradle.properties + Sync

**Step 1:**
Add your Android SDK path into gradle.properties file. (In my case it was)

```
sdk.dir=/Users/rohit_pc/Library/Android/sdk
```

**Step 2:**
Sync Project with Gradle Files

[image]

### Deeper understanding:

When you add **sdk.dir** path and **Sync Project with Gradle Files**. It automatically creates the `local.properties` file for you. If you forget to sync the project you will still get the error

Answer (score 5):

I was creating a project from `ionic 3`. I run `ionic cordova platform add android` and generated the Android Project.
When I tried to run the project then I got the above issue.

At the Project level, I did follow step

Create new file --> Project--> Platform --> android--> local.properties

Add this line:-->  `sdk.dir=/Users/anilgupta/Library/Android/sdk`
and hit sync now. (anilgupta -- use your username for mac)

It builds the new Gradle and syncs with Project.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to editing gradle config files, you can set either `ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in your environment variables.

On Windows, that's usually `<user-home>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

Comment: Seems Cordova doesn't add the necessary file when it can't find the env var ANDROID_HOME.  On linux: add to end of ~/.bashrc : export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk  
Then source ~/.bashrc  
Then cordova platform remove android ; cordova platform add android

Comment: FYI, if you want to have it globally set, you can also set `ANDROID_HOME` in `/etc/environment` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For Me in Ionic -->
Add Flie gradlew.bat and gradlew To Folder platforms\android

Comment: I already had these files in my platform/android folder. Yet I as getting the same error. Creating a new file local.properties with android sdk location solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

## For MacOS

Depending on your bash:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
vi ~/.zshenv
```

Then append this line

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

And finally

```
source ~/.zshenv
```

or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Then close and reopen Android Studio**

Answer (score 0):

Try these paths. It worked for my **M1 mac**. Make sure you have Android Studio installed.

In your terminal:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Paste these paths.:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0)

#SDK exporting
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk

#Tools exporting
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Save the file and run this command:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

A few more things to check:

- make sure you have at least one virtual device downloaded. Check it in AVD manager(Android virtual device manager)
- Compare your android studio SDK manager with the following screenshots.
  [image][image]

PS. I use ~/.zshrc. If you use ~/.bash_profile replace it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when we update the android plaftorm, The local.properties file is missing. To fixing this issue, We can create the file manually and add the SDK path as below.

creating the 'local.properties' file:
Project--> Platform --> android--> local.properties

Adding SDK path:
add the below line to the local.properties file.

sdk.dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

After that, Import the project again to the Android Studio and proceed.